# Add an exception to a Thunderbird filter?

Tags: email, thunderbird, rules, email-filter

In Outlook, I can have a rule that says something like:

If Subject = "ABC"
Move message to folder "XYZ"
Except if my name is in the To: or CC: box

I get a ton of automated emails that are sent to a mailing list, so this is very useful to make sure I see the rare cases where someone forwards one of these automated emails to me with a real question or message.

Is there any way to get this behavior in Thunderbird?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a simple exception like that, generally:

1. Select the ***Match all*** option.
2. Use negative logic for the exception condition(s) -- "is not", "doesn't contain", etc.

Like so:

[(Click for slightly larger)[image: Filter rules]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZSzk.gif)

Comment: Thanks, not sure why I didn't think of that!

Answer (score -1):

http://bit.ly/JagBM1

Short version use more that one criteria, by pressing the + sign, and choose match all of the following.
So it will be like this:

Subject - ABC 
To: - Me

Comment: Why the vote down!

Comment: 1.  Did you think I didn't google it first?  2.  The results from google don't answer my question.  3.  Your answer doesn't answer my question.   Sorry :(